# Rails: How to validate for multiple exact lengths of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want to check a string for exactly 8 or 10 characters.

Is there a possibility with validates_length_of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
class Foo

  validate :check_length

  def check_length
    unless column.size == 8 or column.size == 10
      errors.add(:column, "length must be 8 or 10") 
    end
  end

end
```

You get the idea.

Comment: seems you understood the question much better than I did ;)

Comment: I ran into the same problem before :P

Comment: just a comment: it's better to add errors to the column instead of base (errors display is better handled this way)